# PHP Display Count Total for a Variable within FOREACH loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop and I want to get the count/total of $item for the second echo. Is there a way to count a variable and display the total within a foreach loop? If not, can I do a seperate sql and store the count and pass it to the spot indicated below, or can you only return variables from one sql array ($row in this case)?

The results would look like:
Cost     Item
Cost 1   3
Cost 2    1
Cost 3    4  etc..

However, the items are not stored in the same table as Cost. They are connected by a table ID join. So in the foreach, $cost and $item have to be the results of two seperate queries. My question I guess is, if I do that, how will each row know which item to match with each cost as it loops?

```
foreach ($row as $this) {
echo "<td>$this[cost]</td>"; 
echo "<td> //want to get count of $item variable here! </td>";
```

Comment: what is your second variable - $row['something'] or $item. if $item then is it array or anything else?

Comment: The $item would be the second variable that I want to count, but to get $item requires a COUNT() with multiple joins. Can I insert the entire SQL select with joins inside the <td> In the foreach loop even if this variable is not part of the foreach variable? Or can I have a seperate SQL with joins to get the $item count and then store that result in the <td>?

Comment: I recommend you to use templates in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = count($row);  //counts the total elements of $row array
```

Another method is to place a counter outside foreach loop like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($row as $this) {
  echo "<td>$this[cost]</td>"; 
  echo "<td> //want to get count of {$counter} variable here! </td>";
  $counter++;
}
```

Later edit to understand what I meant:

```
$sql_response = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `product_name`, `product_price` FROM `products` WHERE `product_price`>499");   //let's assume that we have 98 products that meet this condition
$no_of_rows = 0;
if ($sql_response) $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql_response);  //this will count the number of rows that are in $sql_response right now
echo $no_of_rows;  //will output 98 if the query was successfully
```

If you have an array with elements like this:

```
$my_array = array( 0 => array( 'test1' => '123'),
                   1 => array( 'test2' => '123'),
                   2 => array( 'test3' => '123') );

echo count($my_array); //will output 3
```

Comment: Those would be fine except that the count of $items I'm trying to get requires a complex query with joins and I'm not sure if I could simply store the sql result in the foreach because how would the foreach know which results go together on each row?

Comment: @JA4677 I re-edited my answer. Please take a look and see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you are doing. The thing here is that that code doesn't return rows where price = exactly a certain amount like $1.22. I would need to somehow get the count of items where price = PID (price ID) and then dynamically give that count in each row that is returned where PID = PID. Also, I am using PDO. Is it ok to mix that with mysqlii?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to bring two value from different tables. And they are connected with Table_id. For this you don't need to fire two quires. One for Cost and one for Item.

Better way use `join` in the single query. and display at same time.

```
select c.cost, i.item
from cost_table c
left join item_table i on i.id = c.id 
where something = something
```

when you can use in foreach now

```
foreach ($row as $this) {
  echo "<td> $this[cost] </td>"; 
  echo "<td> $this[item] </td>";
}
```

To know about join go here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Hope it useful to you..

Comment: This is the right track for what I'm hoping to do, but I also need it to count() the total of $item and I'm unsure how to do that in a foreach loop.  I assume a second select count query is needed, but then I couldn't use it in the foreach loop which can only handle one query/array I think. Or am I wrong? Anyway, how would I get the count for $item and have it display in the foreach loop so that it is the right count for each row

Comment: I'm confused. :( [1] If $item is array then use `count( $this[item] )`. inside `<td></td>` [2] If you want total of `$item` then use `$temp += $this[$item]` [3]  `$i = 0` outside of foreach and inside `<td> $i++; $this[item] </td>` [4] outside of foreach `echo count($row)`, I hope these different options will help you.